# Exercise that requires some ability to work with sets, cartesian product of sets, and random variables

Tags: probability, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, random-variables, random

I have to solve a tricky exercise that requires some ability to work with sets and random variables. I would like your help with this because I'm unable to see how to proceed.

---

**Construction of $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$:**

Consider $3$ sets $A,B,C$ with $A\equiv \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$, $B\equiv \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$, $C\equiv \{c_1,c_2,c_3\}$.

Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$ be the collection of all subsets of $A$,$B$,$C$ excluding the empty set, i.e., 
$$
\mathcal{A}\equiv \Big\{A, \{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, \{a_3\}, \{a_1,a_2\}, \{a_2, a_3\}, \{a_1,a_3\}\Big\}
$$

$$
\mathcal{B}\equiv \Big\{B, \{b_1\},\{b_2\}, \{b_3\},\{b_1,b_2\}, \{b_2, b_3\}, \{b_1,b_3\}\Big\}
$$

$$
\mathcal{C}\equiv \Big\{C, \{c_1\},\{c_2\}, \{c_3\},\{c_1,c_2\}, \{c_2, c_3\}, \{c_1,c_3\}\Big\}
$$

---

**Construction of $A\times B \times C$:**

Let $\times$ denote the Cartesian Product. 
$A\times B \times C$ is the collection of all ordered $3$-tuples from $A,B,C$, i.e.,
$$
A\times B \times C\equiv \Big\{(a_1,b_1,c_1),(a_1,b_2,c_1), (a_1,b_3,c_1),... \Big\}
$$

---

**Construction of $\mathcal{T}$:**

Consider $\mathcal{T}\equiv \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{C}$. For example, an element $T\in \mathcal{T}$ is
$$
T\equiv \Big(\{a_1,a_2\}, \{b_3\} , \{c_1,c_2\}\Big) 
$$

Each $T\in \mathcal{T}$ is composed of 3 "components". In the example above, the first component is $\{a_1,a_2\}$, the second is $\{b_3\}$, the third is $\{c_1,c_2\}$.

We rewrite each $T\in \mathcal{T}$ as the set of all possible ordered $3$-tuples that can be constructed from its $3$ components. Continuing the example above,
$$
T\equiv \overbrace{\Big(\{a_1,a_2\}, \{b_3\} , \{c_1,c_2\}\Big)}^{\text{Representation 1}}  \equiv \overbrace{\Big\{\overbrace{(a_1,b_3, c_1)}^{\text{ordered $3$-tuple}}, (a_2, b_3, c_1), (a_1,b_3, c_2), (a_2,b_3, c_2)\Big\} }^{\text{Representation 2}}
$$

---

**Construction of $\mathcal{M}$:**

We collect in $\mathcal{M}$ all the subsets of $A\times B\times C$  that cannot be part of $\mathcal{T}$. For example, 
$$
M\equiv \Big\{(a_1,b_3, c_1), (a_2, b_2, c_1)\Big\}
$$
$M$ is not an element of $\mathcal{T}$.

---

**Probability:**
Suppose that I have a random vector  $Y$ with size $3\times 1$ taking value in $A\times B\times C$.

Suppose that I have a random set $S$ taking value in $\mathcal{T}$.

Assume that 
$$
(\star)\hspace{1cm}\mathbb{P}(Y\in T)\geq \mathbb{P}(S\subseteq T ) \text{ } \forall T\in \mathcal{T}
$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes probability measure.

---

**Question:** show that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y\in M)\geq \mathbb{P}(S\subseteq M ) \text{ } \forall M\in \mathcal{M}
$$

---

**Some clarifications:** Random sets are generalisations of random variables to sets.

I believe that to show what I want we should somehow use the fact that $\mathbb{P}(S=M )=0$ $\forall M\in \mathcal{M}$. But I can't see how to proceed.

Also, I realised that every set $M\in \mathcal{M}$ can be written as 
the union of all the subsets of $M$ that belong to $\mathcal{T}$. But I can't see where to use this.

Comment: Note that your representation of the typical element $T\in\mathcal{T}$ as $$T\equiv \Big\{\{a_1,a_2\}, \{b_3\} , \{c_1,c_2\}\Big\}$$ is incorrect. $T$ should be ordered, as:$$T\equiv \Big(\{a_1,a_2\}, \{b_3\} , \{c_1,c_2\}\Big)$$

Comment: OK, let me edit, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure of any approach but maybe try brute forcing for $n=2$, i.e. two sets $A=\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2\}$, proving the assumption $(\star)$, then the question. (The case for $n=1$ is boring).

Comment: Thanks. The assumption $(*)$ should not be proved.

Comment: I try to post my attempt.

**Step 1:** Take any set $M\in \mathcal{M}$ such that the sets $M_1,...,M_k$ are disjoint and belong to $\mathcal{T}$, where $M_1,...,M_k$ are defined as:

- consider all the subsets of $M$ that belong to $\mathcal{T}$

- take the union of the subsets that have non-empty intersections

- name the list of obtained subsets $M_1,...,M_k$

Comment: For example, $M\equiv \Big\{(a_1,b_3, c_1), (a_2, b_1, c_1), (a_1, b_2, c_1)\Big\}$ satisfies the requirements above because -  consider all the subsets of $M$ that belong to $\mathcal{T}$: $\{(a_1,b_3, c_1)\}\in \mathcal{T}$, $\{(a_2, b_1, c_1)\}\in \mathcal{T}$, $\{(a_1, b_2, c_1)\}\in \mathcal{T}$, $\{(a_1,b_3, c_1), (a_1, b_2, c_1)\}\in \mathcal{T}$

- take the union of the subsets that have non-empty intersections: we are left with $\{(a_2, b_1, c_1)\}\in \mathcal{T}$, $\{(a_1,b_3, c_1), (a_1, b_2, c_1)\}\in \mathcal{T}$

Comment: - name the list of obtained subsets $M_1,...,M_k$: $M_1\equiv \{(a_2, b_1, c_1)\}$, $M_2\equiv \{(a_1,b_3, c_1), (a_1, b_2, c_1)\}$

We see that $M_1\in \mathcal{T}$, $M_2\in \mathcal{T}$ and they have empty intersection.

Comment: We show that for any set $M$ with the features above the inequality that we desire is satisfied. Indeed, since $M_1,..., M_k$ are disjoint, we have that
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y\in M)=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}(Y\in M_i)
$$
$$
\mathbb{P}(S\subseteq M)=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}(Y\subseteq M_i)
$$
Moreover, since $M_1,..., M_k$ belong to $\mathcal{T}$, we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}(Y\in M_i)\geq \sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}(Y\subseteq M_i)
$$
Done!

Comment: **Step 2:** What about the sets that cannot be represented as suggested in step 1?